# Python - Screen Scraping Yahoo! Gamechannel for fantasy football

Tags: javascript, python, screen-scraping

So I am trying to scrape Yahoo gamechannel/startracker so i can grab the updates for the fantasy teams when players get points, so i can make graphs in excel. The website url is basically
http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/gamechannel?app=st&lid=60604  <-- the number at the end is the league id

i am kinda new to python.

I tried using beautiful soup first, which worked and got me the code for the page, but not he game channel since it requires javascript.

I got webkit and ran it through that, but where the gamechannel is supposed to be it is telling me to update my flash player. wth? it is up to date.

What do i do?

Comment: the site is in flash, you will not be able to parse it using beautiful soup.

Comment: it looks like selenium might be able to do it, worth a look.http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_selenium.html
http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: wow this looks really complicated

Comment: It's probably also a blatant violation of Yahoo's terms of use, so it's not surprising they don't make it eaasy for you.

Comment: ohhhhhh... didnt know that. guess ill try n use their api

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look into the Yahoo Fantasy Sports API: http://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide/index.html

[`This`](http://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide/player-resource.html#player-resource-samples) is the kind of data you can get.

Would that be of any use or are you trying to get information that isn't available through the API?

PS. You'll need to get an API key here: http://developer.yahoo.com/dashboard/createKey.html

Comment: yeah im thinking about just using that

Comment: Hmm.. when there's the choice of using an API, screen scraping would be a bit insane.

Comment: now i need to convert heir api to python.. why is this so hard =(

Comment: @Acorn i think its what i want. i have no clue how to do it in python atm though